# .NET 5 properly injecting DbContext connection string when using EF Core Power Tools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-power-tools

Hoping for guidance on best practices for setting a connection string in a .NET 5 Web API. I am using EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer a database model and I have a connection string in an appsettings.json file. Trying to figure out how I should apply the steps from [Microsoft's DbContext configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) with my existing setup.

Project setup (shortened for brevity) basically looks like this:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "..."
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            Globals.Configuration = Configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs (autogenerated by EF Core Power Tools)

```
namespace API.Data
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

ExampleController.cs

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("example")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public ActionResult<ApiResponse> GetExample()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that setup alone does not work (example controller would result in a "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method..." error).

I have been working around this by adding a `Connection String` property inside the `ApplicationDbContext.cs` class (after it autogenerates) and setting the property within ConfigureServices inside `Startup.cs` like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

That does allow the use of `using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext() { }` throughout the application, but this connection string setup gets overwritten every time I refresh the model with EF Core Power Tools.

Is there a better example to follow, or what's the best approach here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, as you have configured DB Connection as a option. so there is no need for default constructor of `ApplicationDbContext`

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
    }
```

this should be fine, if you want to set connection string from startup

Now as you have already injecting `ApplicationDbContext` in the startup, you can easily use on controller as a dependency injection rather than creating an new object. because creating new object you'll need to set connection string on that AppDbContext and which is not a good approach!

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("example")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

        ExampleController (private ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) {
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
       }


        [HttpGet("test")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public ActionResult<ApiResponse> GetExample()
        {
            //use db context 
            var something = _applicationDbContext; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Syntax is off just a little bit on the constructor (suggested edit queue says full on your answer), but this obviously works! Thought I tried this but must have overlooked something. Much better than setting it on each object. Thanks, Asif!

Comment: This is easy enough to apply within a controller, but what additional steps are required for using DbContext from DI in a class outside a controller? services.AddScoped<class>() and something else?

Comment: no need, as you already injected in the service here, just inject on the controller and use it 
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));